# Difficulty applying two different scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script embedded on the index page of my site:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bgtoggle").click(function () {
        $(".metro").toggleClass("bgcolorchange");
    });
});
```

The CSS classes the script refers to look like this:

```
.bgcolorchange {
    background-image: url("../images/mthc/imageN.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow : hidden ;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:3;
}

.metro {
background-image: url("../images/mthc/music-therapy-image1.jpg");
z-index : 2;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow : hidden ;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

In a different script file includes this code for handling button clicks:

```
$('.fa-question-circle').parent().on('click', function () {
      $(".metro").css('background-image','url('+"../images/mthc/image2.jpg"+')');
```

I have tested the first script for the background change to happen and this works fine. However when I try to use the script for my "fa-question-circle" button, the change of image doesn't happen and the bgtoggle also doesn't work.

Any suggestions why it no longer functions?

Comment: What is your HTML?  perhaps a parent isn't as you think it should be.

Comment: Is your CSS in a different subfolder to your HTML?  Any `url("../")` type links in a CSS file are _relative to the css file_.  When you do `url("../")` in javascript it's _relative to the page it's currently executing in_

Comment: it seems your second script work well. https://jsfiddle.net/voaap8qt/ , error with your selector ?

Comment: Yes thats a fair point.. <body. metro> is the html

Comment: Ahh the css is in a folder called css so I basically need to take out the.. / At the beginning of the ref to css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the difference in relative paths depending on where that path is specified.  When specified in a CSS file, the path is *relative to that file*.  When you assign a `url()` path to an element in JavaScript, it is *relative to the page in which the script is executing*.

I'm guessing that your stylesheets are stored in a subfolder, so go to the parent before descending into the images folder.  Whereas your JavaScript is probably running in a page that is already in the parent folder, so it doesn't need to "go up one folder" before descending into the images folder.

Comment: yes it worked, only trouble now is once it has worked you can't use the bgtoggle